# Установка Oracle 11G на домашнем компьютере + PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql-developer

Скачал, установил. Службы работают:

[image: Службы:]

Прописал TNS names так:

```
orcl =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
        )
    )
```

ORA Listener:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
)
)
```

Далее поставил PL/SQL Developer, но в окошке ввода данных не отображается моя база:

[image: Вот:]

Все пути в Переменных средах:

[image: Вот:]

Как законнектить в базе девелопер и начать уже писать скрипты?

Comment: попробуйте для начала открыть sqlplus и подуключиться через него

Comment: Вы не упомянули, что создали конект к БД. Забыли или не создавали?

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема вроде как решилась - Установил другую версию девелопера 12 х64, в окошке ввода пароля база появилась. Странно что с 9 версией не то...